# How to make a .gexf from a set of .csv sheets?

Tags: networking

Say I scraped a `friends-list.csv` for each of my Facebook friends and am trying to make a network structure out of them to put into [Gephi](http://gephi.github.io/).

Where would I go from here to make the step from individual friends-lists to a database that shows mutual friendships?

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/gephi/gephi/wiki/Import-CSV-Data?

Comment: @dartonw Yes, this is very helpful, but this assumes I already have the nodes _and_ _edges_ already assigned. I'm trying to find out how get the edges from my input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

Right now you have a list of targets in `source.csv`

You have to add column `Source` to your .csv and under it put your friend's name for every row in that column.

`X's-Friends.csv`

```
Source     Target
X          A
X          B
X          C
X          D
```

After that import your csv as an edge-list into gephi via data laboratory's import spreadsheet and make sure 'create missing nodes' is checked.

Comment: Please tick this as the answer for the benefit of future readers.